# JavaFX. Активный ListView

Tags: javafx, listview

Доброе время суток!
Пишу свое первое не большое приложение с использованием Java FX и возник вопрос.
Есть два ListView на одном Stage. Как узнать какой ListView в данный момент активен в фокусе? Пересмотрел все методы относящиеся к ListView, так не нашел не чего подходящего. Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: [isFocused](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#isFocused--)

Comment: isFocused срабатывает когда выделяешь элемент listview. А в случае пустого listview при его выделении от него толку нет.

Comment: У меня ваша проблема не воспроизводится, `listView.isFocused()` срабатывает если пустой

Comment: Спасибо. Разобрался.

Answer (score 0):

*Main.java*

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

*Controller.java*

```
package sample;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;

public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private ListView list1, list2;

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        System.out.println("initialize");
        list1.focusedProperty().addListener((ov, oldV, newV) -> {
            System.out.println("list1 " + newV);
            System.out.println("list1 " + list1.isFocused());
            System.out.println("list2 " + list2.isFocused());
            System.out.println("------");

        });
        list2.focusedProperty().addListener((ov, oldV, newV) -> {
            System.out.println("list2 " + newV);
            System.out.println("list1 " + list1.isFocused());
            System.out.println("list2 " + list2.isFocused());
            System.out.println("------");
        });
    }
}
```

*sample.fxml*

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
  <?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?> 
  <?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?> 
- <HBox fx:controller="sample.Controller" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.201" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
- <children>
  <ListView fx:id="list1" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" /> 
  <ListView fx:id="list2" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" /> 
  </children>
  </HBox>
```